# Iphone : Problem regarding replacing String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I Want Replace String ':' by '/',

I am  Using this code to replace

```
NSString *newPath = [imgPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"/"];
```

But at a time, I get this error

-[__NSCFDictionary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x664e650

What Should I do ?

Comment: Are you sure imgPath is NSString not NSDictionary?

Comment: What version of XCode and OSX are you running? I believe you need OSX 10.5 or higher to support this method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. imgPath is NSDictionary should be NSString.
2. If imgpath is NSStRING, probably it is released already

Answer (score 0):

I feel there might be some structured organized way the data in your NSString. I faced a similar situation . I had my data with recursive {}. You should replace NSString *imgPath to NSDictionary *dictPath . Having done that read your fields with [dictPath objectForKey:@"key"] than read the fields again in NSString and remove special characters.